# SQL Server Sum Aggregate function - filtering the results set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, aggregate

I have a very generic query that is grouping by the ID and summing up the volume and the getting the maximum address no. When I run it I get the following record count:

```
SELECT (case when m.participant_id=0 then 100000000 + m.member_id else m.participant_id      END) as PID, 
    max(m.address_no) as address_no, sum(e.volume) as P3M_Vol into dbo.tmp_MC_P3M_FuelsPromo_3      
  from dbo.MonthlyDataMart e 
  inner join dbo.v_sr_member m on e.member_id = m.member_id
  where e.member_type_cd = 'MC' 
    and e.year = 2014 and e.month between 2 and 4 
    and e.tran_code in ('PTSEARN','PREMIUM')
    and not exists (select 1 from dbo.v_DNC d where e.member_id = d.member_id)         
group by (case when m.participant_id=0 then 100000000 + m.member_id else m.participant_id END)
```

And I get the following Message:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(16828 row(s) affected)
```

I then removed the sum(e.volume) column in the query (the following code:)

```
SELECT (case when m.participant_id=0 then 100000000 + m.member_id else m.participant_id END) as PID, 
    max(m.address_no) as address_no into dbo.tmp_MC_P3M_FuelsPromo_2        
  from dbo.MonthlyDataMart e 
  inner join dbo.v_sr_member m on e.member_id = m.member_id
  where e.member_type_cd = 'MC' 
    and e.year = 2014 and e.month between 2 and 4 
    and e.tran_code in ('PTSEARN','PREMIUM')
    and not exists (select 1 from dbo.v_DNC d where e.member_id = d.member_id)         
group by (case when m.participant_id=0 then 100000000 + m.member_id else m.participant_id END)
```

And I get different number of rows!

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(34023 row(s) affected)
```

Any idea why this happens? I only removed the aggregate function and the row count are not the same. I am using MS SQL 2000.

Comment: Looks like the column `e.volume` has some NULLs, causing it's ignored in when summing. I made a simple query and you could check it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fd9c/2

Answer (score 0):

Max () and sum () functions are eliminating nulls in this query.
Error is for that columns inside these functions.
The row affected change is for not having sum () inside group by aggrigate functions.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL in the value you are aggregating. Take a good look what exact behavior you want in the query!

The reason your error rows are different is that you are grouping, aggregating and inner joining on potential NULLS. Depending on where records get skipped because of this you can get wildly variable results.